# Ionic 3 fix a div on top of page and keep showing even when a user scroll up and down is not working using sass script

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have this header that i need it to be fixed even when a user scroll up and down or click on an input to fill it up:

```
<ion-card class="fixed">
    <ion-card-header>
      Welcome
    </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

And `.fixed`:

```
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

But the div keep disappearing when I scroll down.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-aeessd).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put this card inside a 
      `<ion-header></ion-header>` ? 
You can add custom styles to ion-header after.

Comment: How is that ? Inside `a` ?

Comment: Can you post more information about your code ? How is structured the page ?